# how to change background image and its height when a function is called

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I have a search page and  I have an advance search option. Only few users can access advance search option. So my div height should increase accordingly and also I need to change my background image to a bigger size. How can I achieve this?

AngularJS:

```
$scope.advanceSearch = function(){
    $scope.adSearch=true;
    $scope.freeSearch = false;
    $scope.showAdvance = "true";  
};
```

Html :

```
<div class="row advanceFilter">
    <a class="aFStyle" ng-click="advanceSearch();">ADVANCE SEARCH</a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.searchPhoto{
    background-image: url("assets/images/searchbg.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    font-family: Monserrat-Regular;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 600px;
    width:1349px;
}
```

After advance search is clicked the `.searchPhoto` to be with different image `Searchmore.jpg` and with `height:900px;` How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Make use of [ngClass](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) directive to dynamically set CSS classes .

```
<div class="row advanceFilter" ng-class="{ \'searchPhoto\': !showAdvance}">
    <a class="aFStyle"ng-click="advanceSearch();">ADVANCE SEARCH</a>
</div>
```

Comment: I did not understand this behavior. Can you elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

You can toggle $scope.advanceSearchToggle value to see if it is advance search and use ng-class to set relevant class

```
<style>
  .searchPhoto {
    background-image: url("assets/images/searchbg.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    font-family: Monserrat-Regular;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 600px;
    width: 1349px;
  }
  .searchPhotoAdvanced {
    background-image: url("assets/images/searchAdvancedbg.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    font-family: Monserrat-Regular;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 900px;
    width: 1349px;
  }
</style>
<div class="row advanceFilter ng-class=" {advanceSearchToggle? 'searchPhotoAdvanced': 'searchPhoto'} ">
      ...
</div>                                                                                                       


$scope.advanceSearchToggle = false;
$scope.advanceSearch = function() {
  $scope.adSearch = true;
  $scope.freeSearch = false;
  $scope.showAdvance = "true";
  $scope.advanceSearchToggle = !$scope.advanceSearchToggle;

};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the trick with [`ng-class`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass).

Here the `.bigSearch` class is applied only when `adSearch == true`:

```
<div class="searchPhoto" ng-class="{bigSearch: adSearch}">
    Search photo
</div>

.bigSearch {
    height: 900px;
}
```

**[Demo in JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s7myw49m/)**

Comment: I tried as given by you , But for me they are overlapping one above other.

Comment: Check the demo JsFiddle, please.